# Using random.uniform(), create a function rand() that generates a single float between −1 and 1. Call rand() once

Tags: python

i want to generate a result for `rand()` but the code has been giving unboundlocal error and saying the maximum recursion depth exceeded please help

```
import random

random.seed(1) # Fixes the seed of the random number generator.
-1<x<1
def rand():
    x =float(rand())  # define `rand` here!
    random.uniform(-1,1)    
rand()
```

and the error is

```
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-401-8945b781ea74> in <module>
      6     x =float(rand())  # define `rand` here!
      7     random.uniform(-1,1)
----> 8 rand()

<ipython-input-401-8945b781ea74> in rand()
      4 -1<x<1
      5 def rand():
----> 6     x =float(rand())  # define `rand` here!
      7     random.uniform(-1,1)
      8 rand()

... last 1 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

<ipython-input-401-8945b781ea74> in rand()
      4 -1<x<1
      5 def rand():
----> 6     x =float(rand())  # define `rand` here!
      7     random.uniform(-1,1)
      8 rand()

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: you are calling `rand` forever inside `rand` - just return `random.uniform(-1, 1)` and say `x = rand()` instead of just `rand`. Little reason to make a function to do this, also.

Comment: i did this  it gave me a syntax error 'return' outside function

Comment: sorry i just found out that the answer the code you directed me to write generated a wrong answer this means the code still have a problem with respect to question and remember that we are using the random.seed(1)

Comment: I think i finally get it, all i need to do is just to remove x

Answer (score 0):

Please note: a function can not call itself. please take the above as example.

function rand() code : def rand(): cant not call itself in its 2nd line which is x =float(rand())  # define `rand` here!

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
random.seed(1)
def rand():
    return(random.uniform(-1, 1))    
rand()
```

## This should work fine as per need